# C++, Boost: how to emulate matrix container memory structure?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

So we have a matrix `A` `N*M` and a vector `B` (of ints or floats)  we want to calculate `A*B`. We want to emulate ways matrices/vectors are held in memory (so to show how differ access speeds depending on how you nest cycles, for example that `ijk` is slower than `kji` when you keep data one way and vice versa another way). Is it possible, and how to do such thing?

Comment: What's wrong with using regular C arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_array/) to set up multidimensional arrays (with convenient indexing) with [different choices of storage layouts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_storage), such as row- and column-major.